# What's the simplest way to persist a small string in my FireFox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

I'm writing an extension, and I'd like to save a small API key so that it is always available in future sessions.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Firefox preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/A_Brief_Guide_to_Mozilla_Preferences) should do the job.